Android: ConnectionsClient's not connecting, endpointId null might be the problem? (not sure)
Trying, for the first time, to make an app that can communicate with another app. Goals is to track stuff for a complex board game so you don't have to run around the table and/or keep asking each other.
I am trying to use the Android Nearby Connections API but even though I feel like I am following the examples correctly it just doesn't work. endpointId seems to always be null and that is required to send payloads.
So, my manifests has the permissions
<!-- Required for WIFI Direct -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

I ask for the location permission at runtime, which works, because after checking manually I can see that the app has indeed loaction permissions.
I tried debugging and setting up all kinds of logs/toasts, but nothing that gets me closer.
MainActivity
`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private boolean hasStarted;
private int counter = 0;

private boolean hasInternetPermission = false;
private boolean hasWifiAccessPermission = false;
private boolean hasWifiChangePermission = false;
private boolean hasCoarseLocationPermission = false;
private boolean hasFineLocationPermission = false;
private boolean hasBluetoothCodePermission = false;
private boolean hasBluetoothCodeAdminPermission = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    hasStarted = false;

    Spinner factionSelectSpinner = findViewById(R.id.faction_select_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.dropdown_factions, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
    factionSelectSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    factionSelectSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            String selectedItem = parentView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        }
    });

    Button findGroupButton = findViewById(R.id.find_group_button);
    findGroupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            hasInternetPermission = askForPermission(android.Manifest.permission.INTERNET, PERMISSION_INTERNET_CODE);
            hasWifiAccessPermission = askForPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, PERMISSION_ACCESS_WIFI_CODE);
            hasWifiChangePermission = askForPermission(android.Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE, PERMISSION_CHANGE_WIFI_CODE);
            hasCoarseLocationPermission = askForPermission(android.Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE, PERMISSION_CHANGE_WIFI_CODE);
            hasFineLocationPermission = askForPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION_CODE);
            hasBluetoothCodePermission = askForPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH, PERMISSION_BLUETOOTH_CODE);
            hasBluetoothCodeAdminPermission = askForPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN, PERMISSION_BLUETOOTH_ADMIN_CODE);
            performFindGroupActionAfterPermissionCheck();

        }
    });

    Button testButton = findViewById(R.id.test_button);
    testButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AppExtension app = (AppExtension) getApplicationContext();
            app.sendMessage("Test message");

        }
    });
}

private boolean askForPermission(String permission, Integer requestCode) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
    } else {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (permissions.length > 0 && grantResults.length > 0) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permissions[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case PERMISSION_INTERNET_CODE:
                    hasInternetPermission = true;
                    break;
                case PERMISSION_ACCESS_WIFI_CODE:
                    hasWifiAccessPermission = true;
                    break;
                case PERMISSION_CHANGE_WIFI_CODE:
                    hasWifiChangePermission = true;
                    break;
                case PERMISSION_COARSE_LOCATION_CODE:
                    hasCoarseLocationPermission = true;
                    break;
                case PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION_CODE:
                    hasFineLocationPermission = true;
                    break;
                case PERMISSION_BLUETOOTH_CODE:
                    hasBluetoothCodePermission = true;
                    break;
                case PERMISSION_BLUETOOTH_ADMIN_CODE:
                    hasBluetoothCodeAdminPermission = true;
                    break;
            }
            performFindGroupActionAfterPermissionCheck();

        }
    }
}

private void performFindGroupActionAfterPermissionCheck() {
    if (allPermissionsAccepted() && !hasStarted) {
        counter++;
        hasStarted = true;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "perform " + counter, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        AppExtension app = (AppExtension) this.getApplicationContext();
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        app.findGroup();
        // Post a Runnable to be executed after 10 seconds (10,000 milliseconds)
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Code to be executed after 10 seconds
                doSomething();
            }
        }, 10000); // 10,000 milliseconds = 10 seconds
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cant  " + allPermissionsAccepted() + " " + hasStarted, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}

private boolean allPermissionsAccepted() {
    return hasInternetPermission && hasWifiAccessPermission && hasWifiChangePermission && hasCoarseLocationPermission
            && hasFineLocationPermission && hasBluetoothCodePermission && hasBluetoothCodeAdminPermission;
}

private void doSomething() {
    AppExtension app = (AppExtension) this.getApplicationContext();
    app.stopFindingGroup();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done " + counter, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    hasStarted = false;

}

}
`
AppExtension
`public class AppExtension extends Application {
ConnectionsClient connectionsClient;
String mEndpointID;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

public void findGroup() {
    connectionsClient = Nearby.getConnectionsClient(this);
    stopFindingGroup();

    connectionsClient.startAdvertising(getDeviceName(), SERVICE_ID, connectionLifeCycleCallback, new AdvertisingOptions(Strategy.P2P_CLUSTER));
    connectionsClient.startDiscovery(SERVICE_ID, endpointDiscoveryCallback, new DiscoveryOptions(Strategy.P2P_CLUSTER));
}

public void stopFindingGroup() {
    connectionsClient.stopDiscovery();
    connectionsClient.stopAdvertising();
}

private String getDeviceName() {
    // Get the device brand and manufacturer
    String brand = Build.BRAND;
    String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
    String model = Build.MODEL;
    return manufacturer + " " + model + " (" + brand + ")";
}

private final ConnectionLifecycleCallback connectionLifeCycleCallback = new ConnectionLifecycleCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionInitiated(@NonNull String endpointId, @NonNull ConnectionInfo connectionInfo) {
        // Automatically accept the connection
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onConnectionInitiated acceptConnection " + endpointId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        connectionsClient.acceptConnection(endpointId, payloadCallback);
        mEndpointID = endpointId;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionResult(@NonNull String endpointId, ConnectionResolution result) {
        if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            // We're connected! Can now send and receive data.
            mEndpointID = endpointId;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onConnectionResult isSuccess " + endpointId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            // Connection failed
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onConnectionResult failed " + endpointId + " " + result.getStatus().getStatusCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(@NonNull String endpointId) {
        // We've been disconnected from this endpoint.
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onDisconnected " + endpointId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};

private final EndpointDiscoveryCallback endpointDiscoveryCallback = new EndpointDiscoveryCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onEndpointFound(@NonNull String endpointId, @NonNull DiscoveredEndpointInfo info) {
        // An endpoint was found. Request a connection to it.
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "EndpointDiscoveryCallback  onEndpointFound " + endpointId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        connectionsClient.requestConnection(getDeviceName(), endpointId, connectionLifeCycleCallback);
        mEndpointID = endpointId;
    }

    @Override
    public void onEndpointLost(@NonNull String endpointId) {
        // A previously discovered endpoint is no longer available.
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "EndpointDiscoveryCallback  onEndpointLost " + endpointId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
};

private final PayloadCallback payloadCallback = new PayloadCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPayloadReceived(@NonNull String endpointId, Payload payload) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onPayloadReceived " + endpointId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (payload.getType() == Payload.Type.BYTES) {
            String receivedMessage = new String(payload.asBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            // Handle the received message
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "message received " + receivedMessage + " end " + endpointId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPayloadTransferUpdate(@NonNull String endpointId, @NonNull PayloadTransferUpdate update) {
        // Track progress of file transfers
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onPayloadTransferUpdate " + endpointId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
};

public void saveDataOnClose() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_TAG, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    editor.apply();
}

public void sendMessage(String message) {
    // Create a Payload from the message
    Payload payload = Payload.fromBytes(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "payload " + message + " " + mEndpointID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mEndpointID)) {
        // Send the payload to the connected endpoint
        connectionsClient.sendPayload(mEndpointID, payload)
                .addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {
                    // Message sent successfully
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                    // Handle the error
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                });
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "mEndpointid was null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

}`
